# Will this method of building AWS S3 presigned URLs work?

Tags: .net, amazon-s3

I have a .NET API that connects to a S3 bucket. There are multiple client apps that need access to images in the S3 bucket. I'm thinking about building .NET API method that returns a presigned S3 URL. It would look something like this (pseudocode):

```
[HttpGet("Image")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Image(string key)
{
    // Run code related to authentication here. Leaving this out for brevity.

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
        {
            BucketName = "mybucket",
            Key = key,
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)
        };

        string url = _amazonS3.GetPreSignedURL(request);
        return Redirect(url);
    }
    else
    {
        return StatusCode(401, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

The idea would be a client could display this image using a img tag such as:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Image", "MyController", new { key = "123.png" )" />
```

Assuming of course the client is already authenticated. So basically the API generates a presigned URL and then returns a 302 redirect result. I'm wondering if this would be problematic in any way? I'm aware that I could use CloudFront to display the images on the front-end. But we're hoping to not have to set up CloudFront as we currently do not use it at all. It's possible for 100 or more images to load at once. Should I be worried about performance? Is there a simple way to cache the result of the controller method? Maybe use ResponseCache attribute? Thanks!

Comment: That'll work.  Generally speaking, since generating a presigned URL is a client-side only activity, there's little reason to cache them.  I would say that since you're building them on the fly, there's little reason to have them expire in 5 minutes, 30 seconds would be plenty of time.

Comment: Thanks Anon. I should have clarified that I was more worried about the client apps making 100 requests to get images. Each one would call the method above. I thought about using the ResponseCache attribute. I'll think I'll just give this method a shot. The alternative is that we store a bunch of presigned URLs in the DB for the apps to grab. I really hate that solution though.